# Spring boot : LAZY Loading not working for @EmbeddedId field

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

I have EmbeddedId which has field which need to be loaded lazy. In service class on fetching TeacherStudent it also fetch student EAGERLY which should be LAZY fetch. what changes are needed to make student being fetched as lazy ?

TeacherStudent.class ---> making student load as lazy

```
class TeacherStudent
{
 public static final String TEACHER = "TeacherStudentPk.teacher";
 public static final String STUDENT = "TeacherStudentPk.student";

@EmbeddedId
TeacherStudentPk teacherStudentPk = new TeacherStudentPk();

@ToString.Exclude
@Transient
Teacher teacher;

@ToString.Exclude
@Transient
Student student; 
}
```

Getting Teacher Student data from teacher table

TeacherStudentpk.class

```
 @Embeddable
class TeacherStudentPk{
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY , optional = false)
 @JoinColumn(name = "student_pk") 
 Student student;   **<-------------  student marked as lazy**

 Teacher teacher;

}
```

TecherService.class

```
class TeacherService{

   void getTeacherStudent(Teacher teacher){
       Set<TeacherStudent> teacherStudent = 
 teacher.getTeacherStudent(); **<-----eager 
 fetching student which is of lazy type** 
   }  
}
```

How should I change in TeacherStudent table to make student as fetch lazy ?

Comment: please provide your TeacherStudentPk, format your code and provide a minimalistic reproducible code to make it easier for us to investigate

Comment: I have updated code as required

Comment: How do you determine that the student is fetched eagerly? Please show the executed SQL.

Comment: By printing sql query in logs using org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG . There are extra calls to fetch students table